# Calling a function in a case statement within select statement is that possible(simply can I have a while loop within case statement)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case, sql-server-2014-express

I wanted to select the data according to the case like the example below

```
    select Id, name, address,
    case when department = CIS then @date1 as Date
         else @date2 as Date
```

where `@date1` and `@date2` should be get it from function. How can I do it?
@date1 should be an output of while loop. Please help me to resolve it with an example

Comment: `select Id, name, address,
case 
 when department = CIS then @date1
 else @date2 END AS DATTE
`

Answer (score 1):

You can only have a single column alias, which comes after the entire expression. Additionally, note that you'e missing the `end` keyword:

```
SELECT id, 
       name,
       address,
       CASE WHEN department = 'CIS' THEN @date1 ELSE @date2 END AS [date]
```

EDIT:
Also note that for a simple equality check you can use the simpler syntax:

```
SELECT id, 
       name,
       address,
       CASE department WHEN 'CIS' THEN @date1 ELSE @date2 END AS [date]
```

Comment: SQL server uses `[date]` instead of `\`date\``. The latter is MySQL syntax ;-)

Comment: @RobIII yup, true. Wasn't paying attention, thanks. Edited and fixed.

Comment: @Mureinik what my question was how to call a function to get date1 &  date2 
what I wanted to do is through a while loop I should find the value there..
is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot an `end` to your case statement

This should work:

```
select Id, name, address,
    case when 
         department = CIS then @date1 
         else @date2  
     end as "Date"
```

Comment: `This should work` No it won't since you (still) have an alias in the first case; it should *follow* the case (where you *also* have an alias) ;)